# How to write from ReactNative to Apple's unified log in the Simulator

Tags: javascript, react-native, logging, ios-simulator

I'd like to log some values in ReactNative but not to the console or to a file, I'd like to log data to Apple's unified log while I'm running in the iPhone Simulator.

In other words, I'd like to achieve the same as this line in Swift that writes to the log and the data can be inspected in Console.app:

```swift
os_log("This is a debug log line")
```

Is there a way to do that with JavaScript in ReactNative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this package [react-native-os-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-os-logger)

Comment: Hey, it's pretty simple but this is all I need for now, thanks!